# Android studio / Unable to launch test App in emulator due to VPN (zscaler)

Tags: android, networking, zscaler

can advise how to solve this issue.

Testing an app created by the Mobile team, having error requesting for update whenever Zscaler(VPN) is ON, however if Turn off the VPN, It's working fine. can advise is there any settings' to bypass while Zscaler is ON, thank you
Error Msg when open the app with zscaler ON.
(Your App is not up to date)
This feature is not available on older app version

Need some Guide, what need to be done, thank  you